# optgroup in dropdown using struts

Tags: struts

Can anyone please help in implementing the same functionality of optgroup using struts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of creating select groups using [Struts tags](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html).

You will have to resort to using the plain HTML tag `<optgroup>` tag and create your select options by using either the JSTL [`<c:forEach>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag or the Struts [`<logic:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-logic.html#iterate) tag.

Such a tag [was added in Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/optgroup.html) but for Struts 1 there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've solved my issue with similar kind of answer.